# Disable autocomplete for Chrome 66

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

With chrome 66 I couldn't find a way to disable autocomplete on text inputs like it used to work. I tried `autocomplete="off"` and `autocomplete="new-password"` which worked until Chrome 63 I think but doesn't anymore.

Is there a new way to disable this feature ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: Try `aria-autocomplete="none"` and see if anything changes? @SSH. Also doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/50238206/2830850 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ran into this -- Google looks at the fields `id` or `name` to determine if it has saved data for that field.  As a site author, use a randomly generated name/id, and/or add an `autocomplete=<random string>` to the field.

See this playground: https://jsfiddle.net/mfdc22pz/1/

BTW Chrome Canary (68) fixes this bug!

In Short:
Add random tags like:
`name="foo_90553-4"`

Comment: Checked this with Chrome 68 and confirmed autocomplete is gone! I guess we'll just recommend people using IE or Firefox until Chrome 68 gets released. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Moos When you say Chrome 68 fixes the bug, do you mean you were able to get it to honor the `autocomplete=off` flag? Just tested in Canary 69 and can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Google looks at the name attribute only. Not the id. Using a random name is troublesome if you're going to be looking at post data.

Comment: Yes, some on my version 69

Comment: Working in March 2019

Answer (score 2):

I resolved using a little jQuery (but you can use a simple javascript).

The problem is that chrome looks at the **name** and/or the **id** of your fields.
The only solution I found is to remove those attributes, add an **data-name attribute** with the real name of the field, and re-attach the name attribute after the submit using javascript.

There is an example

```
<form onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" data-name="dateStart" class="form-control" />
</form>


<script>
function formSubmit(form) {
  console.log(form);
  $(form).find('.form-control').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name', $(this).data('name'));
  });
  console.log(form);
  query = jQuery(form).serialize();
  window.open("/YOUR_URL/?" + query, "_self");
  return false;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.
Work around with insert invisible input make it like first input on page.

[Html]
...


...
[css]
...
.invisible_input{height: 0.1px;position: absolute;margin-top: -500px;}
...

But waiting for answer from chrome developer:/
I hope this help you!
[image]

Comment: Tried every permutation of autofill / autocomplete "off", "foobar", etc.  The hidden input was that only thing that worked.  Thanks!

Comment: It's seem chrome newest version have fixed this issue. Check out newest version off chrome(V.67.....)

Answer (score 0):

What's working for me is using a non-password input that pretends to have a password mask - battling the browser vendors to turn off autocomplete on actual password fields will probably end in frustration..

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yp3pyl4rkv

A similar approach with more features is at https://github.com/karaggeorge/react-better-password